# Unable to retrieve details from Microsoft Bot Builder TeamsContext

Tags: c#, sdk, botframework, microsoft-teams

Bot framework update to V4 (4.4.3): Looks there is lot of changes in the complete structure in usage of bot framework. In our case, teams user is initiating a chat to bot (our application) and bot could able to receive the chat. But, to identify the teams user email Id, teams Id, etc., we need to use TeamsContext to extract the details. But the teamsContext.Team.Id, teamsContext.Tenant.Id, etc are NULL. Our objective is to retrieve the teams user details such as name, email, tenant id, etc..

```
// Before doing Teams specific stuff, get hold of the TeamsContext
ITeamsContext teamsContext = turnContext.TurnState.Get<ITeamsContext>();

// From there we can get the Team ID, Channel ID, and Tenant ID off of the incoming activity
string incomingTeamId = teamsContext.Team.Id;
string incomingChannelid = teamsContext.Channel.Id;
string incomingTenantId = teamsContext.Tenant.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the teamsContext.Team.Id, teamsContext.Tenant.Id, etc are NULL. Our objective is to retrieve the teams user details such as name, email, tenant id, etc

As far as I've tried, even just after Teams Nuget package was out, these values were never provided on a user-bot direct interaction. They are only set on a conversation interaction (with several users).

I don't think it is linked to Bot SDK 4.4.3, but just the initial behaviour of this method (honestly I was also surprised about that when I made my tests)

Comment: But, do we have any way to retrieve the user name, email who initiated the chat through teams. These are essential for any bot application when someone initiated chat from teams client. Any solution for this?

Comment: Not directly. But in the From / Recipient values, there is in Teams an `aadObjectId` which is the Azure AD Object ID of your user, so you should be able to get the user details with it in your bot code, if you have sufficient rights on your AD

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks Nicolas.